# How to solve this question on magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Create a custom colum in the product grid. It shows that how many size options available against that product. If the product has (S,M,L) then 3, if product has (XS,S,M,L,XL) then 5 and if product has (X,M,L and Color options like Green, Blue, Black) then shows 6, in other words show how many child products does this product have? if simple product then it shows 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like that to add the column and you specify in the model the data you want to put in it:

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"> 
    <columns name="product_columns"> 
        <column name="manage_stock" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="76"> 
            <settings> 
                <addField>true</addField> 
                <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\CountChildProduct"/> 
                <filter>select</filter> 
                <dataType>select</dataType> 
                <sortable>false</sortable> 
                <label translate="true">Child products</label> 
            </settings> 
        </column> 
    </columns> 
</listing>
```